# Getting in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError) after installing gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-7

Im using windows. I wanted to include font awesome icons to my project and so I added `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.2'` to my gem file did a  `bundle install` and got this:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
Installing rb-fsevent 0.11.2
Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
Fetching sass 3.7.4
Installing sass 3.7.4
Fetching font-awesome-sass 4.7.0
Installing font-awesome-sass 4.7.0
Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 113 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.

* If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
  primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install

* If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
  sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme

* For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
  https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
```

After trying to run my server I'd get this:

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> rails s
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'     
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/Documents/GitHub/WindhoekTradespersonPlatform/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'   
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform>
```

**My Gemfile**

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "3.2.2"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem "rails", github: "rails/rails", branch: "main"
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.8"

# The original asset pipeline for Rails [https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails]
gem "sprockets-rails"

gem "activeadmin"

gem "sassc"

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'

gem "devise", github: "heartcombo/devise", branch: "main"

gem "geocoder"

gem "carrierwave", "~> 3.0"

gem 'faker', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'

gem "jquery-rails"

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem "sqlite3", "~> 1.4"

# Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "puma", "~> 5.0"

# Use JavaScript with ESM import maps [https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails]
gem "importmap-rails"

# Hotwire's SPA-like page accelerator [https://turbo.hotwired.dev]
gem "turbo-rails"

# Hotwire's modest JavaScript framework [https://stimulus.hotwired.dev]
gem "stimulus-rails"

# Build JSON APIs with ease [https://github.com/rails/jbuilder]
gem "jbuilder"

# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
 gem "redis", "~> 4.0"

# Use Kredis to get higher-level data types in Redis [https://github.com/rails/kredis]
# gem "kredis"

# Use Active Model has_secure_password [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword]
# gem "bcrypt", "~> 3.1.7"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ]

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem "bootsnap", require: false

# Use Sass to process CSS
# gem "sassc-rails"

# Use Active Storage variants [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images]
# gem "image_processing", "~> 1.2"

group :development, :test do
  # See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-debug-gem
  gem "debug", platforms: %i[ mri mingw x64_mingw ]
end

group :development do
  # Use console on exceptions pages [https://github.com/rails/web-console]
  gem "web-console"

  # Add speed badges [https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler]
  # gem "rack-mini-profiler"

  # Speed up commands on slow machines / big apps [https://github.com/rails/spring]
  # gem "spring"
end

group :test do
  # Use system testing [https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing]
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"

end

gem "pagy", "~> 6.2"

gem 'byebug'

# gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'
```

tried commenting it out `# gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'`
But that hasn't changed anything

I've tried doing a `gem uninstall ffi`and I get this message:

```
gem uninstall ffi

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        ffi-1.16.3-x64-mingw-ucrt

rb-inotify-0.10.1 depends on ffi (~> 1.0)
ruby-vips-2.2.0 depends on ffi (~> 1.12)
sassc-2.4.0 depends on ffi (~> 1.9)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]
```

by selecting `y` brings the following message:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ apply2files - C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/3.2/ffi_c.so
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2342:in `unlink'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2342:in `block in remove_file'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2350:in `platform_support'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2341:in `remove_file'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2330:in `remove'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:1470:in `block in remove_entry'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2389:in `block (2 levels) in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2393:in `postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2388:in `block in postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `each'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:2387:in `postorder_traverse'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:1468:in `remove_entry'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:1323:in `block in rm_r'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:1319:in `each'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/fileutils.rb:1319:in `rm_r'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:254:in `block in remove'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:371:in `safe_delete'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:254:in `remove'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:166:in `uninstall_gem'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:143:in `uninstall'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:198:in `uninstall'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:184:in `uninstall_gem'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:178:in `block in uninstall_specific'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:170:in `each'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:170:in `uninstall_specific'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/uninstall_command.rb:136:in `execute'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:327:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:252:in `invoke_command'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:192:in `process_args'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:150:in `run'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
        C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/gem.cmd:18:in `<main>'
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform>
```

**Update**
I uninstalled the following

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> gem uninstall rb-fsevent

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        rb-fsevent-0.11.2

If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled rb-fsevent-0.11.2
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> gem uninstall rb-inotify

You have requested to uninstall the gem:

sass-listen-4.0.0 depends on rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled rb-inotify-0.10.1
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> gem uninstall sass 
Remove executables:
        sass, sass-convert, scss

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  n
Executables and scripts will remain installed.
Successfully uninstalled sass-3.7.4
```

I got to here

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> gem uninstall ffi

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        ffi-1.16.3-x64-mingw-ucrt

ruby-vips-2.2.0 depends on ffi (~> 1.12)
sassc-2.4.0 depends on ffi (~> 1.9)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
```

but didn't go any further in fear of breaking something

**UPDATE**
Saw somewhere that said i should try running `gem install ffi --platform=ruby` and it would fix the issue. A ran it and got the following. Once again too scared to continue try this

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> gem install ffi --platform=ruby
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.16.3
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.16.3
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.16.3
Done installing documentation for ffi after 13 seconds
1 gem installed

A new release of RubyGems is available: 3.4.10 → 3.4.22!
Run gem update --system 3.4.22 to update your installation.
```

**UPDATE 2**
As suggested I updated my Gemfile to have `gem "font-awesome-sass", "~> 6.4.2"` and ran a `bundle install` but got this:

```
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform>  bundle install 
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching font-awesome-sass 6.4.2
Installing font-awesome-sass 6.4.2
Bundle complete! 26 Gemfile dependencies, 109 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
PS C:\Users\XW3R\Documents\GitHub\WindhoekTradespersonPlatform> rails s
<internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/native.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc.rb:31:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc-rails.rb:3:in `require_relative'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc-rails.rb:3:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap/engine.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:61:in `register_rails_engine'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:11:in `load!'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/lib/bootstrap.rb:75:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'     
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.19/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/Documents/GitHub/WindhoekTradespersonPlatform/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:137:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:134:in `perform'   
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/thor-1.3.0/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Users/XW3R/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in 
`require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your "font-awesome-sass" gem beacause old version might be not supported you can replace your gem with below version

```
gem "font-awesome-sass", "~> 6.4.2"
```

so when i am trying this version as you are using

```
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.2
```

so i got below error as you mentioned
[image]

so i tried to upgrade from 4.6 to 6.4.2 so it works fine and not getting any error.
**hoping you are doing bundle install after upgrading your gem.**
and you are talking about ffe gem so it will directly install/upgrade because it is needed for font-awesome-saas gem
[image: ffi gem dependent for sassc]

Comment: will that get rid of the ffi issue though? This is the version I installed `# gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.7.0'` but I commented it out

Comment: this version is functioning perfectly on my system so you should try it

Comment: What version are you using. I updated it but no change

Comment: ruby 3.1.3 and rails 7.0.8

Comment: i tried this version gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.6', '>= 4.6.2' but it gives me same error ruby sass has reached end of life so i upgrade to latest version then it's working fine

Comment: What RubyGem version are you using? It's telling me:
`A new release of RubyGems is available: 3.4.10 → 3.4.22!`
But im far to scared to make any changes. I followed what you said however the problem of me trying to run rails and getting the `:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)` persists. I'm not sure if font-awesome is the issue. If you check the updates I added more detail to my issue thank you

Comment: i updated my answer can u check that i don't think it is rubygems issue

Comment: Hi friend. Tried the update. If you see in my updated question the issue persists even after.

Answer (score 0):

So after much fighting, which included re-installing ruby, I figured the issue was this

In my `Gemfile` I changed this:

```
gem "sassc"

gem "bootstrap", "~> 4.3.1"
```

To this:

```
gem "dartsass-sprockets"

gem "bootstrap", "~> 5.3.2"
```

How I understand it from the [bootstrap gem repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem#installation)

> Add bootstrap to your Gemfile:
>
> `gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.3.2'` This gem requires a Sass engine, so make
> sure you have one of these two gems in your Gemfile:
>
> `dartsass-sprockets`: Dart Sass engine, recommended but only works for
> Ruby 2.6+ and Rails 5+
> `sassc-rails`: SassC engine, deprecated but compatible with Ruby 2.3+
>
> and Rails 4 Also ensure that `sprockets-rails` is at least v2.3.2.

The old bootstrap depended on `sassc`, so replacing that with `dartsass-sprockets` did the trick for me. There was a bunch of other stuff I did, so in case this exact thing doesn't work for you, feel free to ask.